# C# X509Certificate2 added on a remote server X509Store cannot be exported

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I have been digging through the site for 3 days now and have found lots of solutions for local imports, but not this issue with remote importing of a X509Certificate2 object.

Using the following code, I can get the .pfx file to import and say that it has a private key, but it will not mark it as exportable.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, 
                                certPwd,
                                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                                X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | 
                                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var certStore = new X509Store($@"\\{server}\My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
certStore.Add(cert);
certStore.Close();
```

It connects to the remote server, it installs the certificate, but then because it is not exportable, we cannot bind the certificate in IIS.

I have tried using X509Chain and X509Collection as well, but these again import the certificate, but make it non-exportable.

I'm beating my head against the desk here.  Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

The servers are all Win2k8 or higher (most are 2012).

---edit below---
Some extra clarification.

- I created a Rest API that attempts to do the actual installation of the cert on the remote server.
- The Application Pool identity is in the administrator group on the server on which I am trying to install the cert on.
- I wrote a tool today using Win32API's to do the installation and the tool worked.  When I added the code to the Rest API, the cert is still not bindable to IIS https sites.

I am leaning towards this being a User Context issue.

---end edits---

Thanks!
-Ed

Comment: Whatever magic transfers keys across the machine boundary probably doesn't respect the exportable setting.  You'll probably need to import locally if you care about exportability.

Comment: IIS does not require exportable keys.

Comment: All we know is that when we try to bind the certs to the IP addresses, they fail when we cannot export them and bind when we can export them.

Comment: Without the "exportable" flag the cert can't be bound to an IIS site. 
Experiencing the exact same issue, had the hope that this would have been answer :( so sad it doesn't, will let you know if I find something.

Comment: Just wondering if you have also attempted to import a cert using PowerShell?